# Не добавлять уникальный объект

Tags: javascript

Есть массив обьектов, куда по каждому клику добавляются пушится по одному объекту
такой структуры {'name':'Alex', 'order':123}
Как сделать проверку, чтобы не пушить в массив объекты с одинаковыми именами?
Вижу это как-то так:

```
  let orders = [];
  let obj = {'name':'Alex', 'order':123};

  if (this.orders.length === 0) {
     this.orders.push(obj);
    } else {
    for (const item of this.orders) {
    if (orders.name === obj.name) {
    return;
    } else {
    this.selectedServices.push(selected);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!this.orders.find(i => i.name == obj.name)) {
  this.orders.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Суппер, спасибо! Мне для IE тоже нужно, там find не поддерживается

Comment: @Lex https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill  или цикл